# Can I create two types equal derived from number or string and sum or concat these?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying understand Generic Class in TypeScript, but, I expected a behaviour and I came across another view so different

Instead of using (that work's like a charm)

```
class Concat<T extends string, U extends T> {
    private result: string;
    public n1: U;
    public n2: U;
    init(n1: U, n2: U) {
        this.result = this.n1 + this.n2;
    }
}

class Sum<T extends number, U extends T> {
    private result: number;
    public n1: U;
    public n2: U;
    init(n1: U, n2: U) {
        this.result = this.n1 + this.n2;
    }
}

var concat = new Concat<string, string>();
concat.init("A", "A");

var sum = new Sum<number, number>();
sum.init(1, 3);
```

Use that or something similar give me an error

```
class OperatorPlus <T extends number | string, U extends T> {
    private result: number | string;

    public n1: U;
    public n2: U;
    init(n1: U, n2: U) {
        this.result = this.n1 + this.n2;
    }
}

var operator = new OperatorPlus<string, string>();
operator.init("A", "B");
```

**Someone could help me?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your example and it doesn't works so well...

**In this case**

```
class OperatorPlus<
  U extends string | number,
  U1 = (string extends U ? number extends U ? never : string : number),
  > {
    private result: U1;

    public n1: U1;
    public n2: U1;
    init(n1: U1, n2: U1) {
        this.result = (this.n1 as any) + this.n2;
    }
}

var operator = new OperatorPlus<number>();
operator.init(1, 2)// OK for TS
var operator2 = new OperatorPlus<string, string>();
operator2.init('A', 'B') // OK for TS
var operator2 = new OperatorPlus<number, string>();
operator2.init('A', 'B') // OK for TS, but it's not my intention <----------------
```

**This is my solution :)**

```
class Plus<T, U extends (T extends number ? number : string)> {

    private result: U;

    constructor(n1: U, n2: U) {
        this.result = (n1 as any) + n2;
        console.log(this.result);
    }
}

var p = new Plus<number, string>("A", "B"); // TS complains about different types
```

Comment: That is fine but will fail if you put string | number. Just saying

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript disallows using `+` operator for anything which doesn't evaluate to `number` or to `string`. Your combination will evaluate to `number | string`, it means that when you will put as `n1` number and as `n2` number `+` will perform addition, and when one of operands will be `string` will perform concatenation, it means `+` behaves in two ways.

This exactly is restricted by TS. Lately I wrote article which exactly explains why TS is doing so - [Why TypeScript restricts + operator](https://dev.to/macsikora/this-is-why-typescript-restricts-operator-i0f)

Check also that I can use `number | string` as generic types in your example:

```
var operator = new OperatorPlus<number | string, number | string>();
operator.init("A", 1); // no error
```

If something extends `number | string` then it means it can be also `number | string`, and both operands can be such, and you exactly get into case where TS is strict about that.

---

We can have it working but inside there needs to be fallback to unsound. But the generic will be blocked for using union type, union type instance will not be usable. Consider:

```
class OperatorPlus<
  U extends string | number,
  U1 = (string extends U ? number extends U ? never : string : number),
  > {
    private result: U1;

    public n1: U1;
    public n2: U1;
    init(n1: U1, n2: U1) {
        this.result = (this.n1 as any) + this.n2;
    }
}

var operator = new OperatorPlus<number>();
operator.init(1, 2)// ok
var operator2 = new OperatorPlus<string, string>();
operator2.init('A', 'B') //ok
var operator3 = new OperatorPlus<string | number>();
operator3.init() // cannot be used both arguments never type
```

Yes `as any` not looks nice, but the operator is now restricted to work only with `string` or `number` and never with a mix.

Comment: My intention is to prevent two different types, like operator.init(number, string).

Comment: Can I enable + operator in some way?

Comment: Will prepare smth. Wait a moment